# Preference Background Color Blinking

Tags: android, preference

I managed to change my preference activity's background color, but when I focus/scroll it, it blinks. Please help me solve this. This is how i change my background...

```
public class ConfigActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    findViewById(android.R.id.list).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
}
```

}

Comment: Add some code, how did you change the background color ? If you use a PreferenceFragment, try overriding onViewCreated :@Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
 }

Comment: Please add more details your question. Some code examples or anything. They way it is right now is very hard to offer any help.

Comment: i edited the question. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in your layout.

See also http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html